# Is it possible to define custom Power Nap tasks/behavior?

Tags: macos, sleep, osx-mavericks

In OS X 10.8, [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032) was introduced. When it's turned on, a machine can perform tasks like checking for new email and backing up using Time Machine.

I was wondering if it is at all possible to define your own Power Nap tasks/behaviors to be executed alongside the aforementioned official ones, and if so, how. For example, I may want my machine to run a command that updates my MacPorts packages while it's asleep and connected to a power source.

Thanks!